# Symfony login throttling only working on localhost

Tags: symfony, authentication

I've been trying to get Symfony's (using 6.0.2) login throttling to work on my Ubuntu 20.04 server running Apache, but I can't seem to make it work. The curious part is that it works on localhost on my macOS.

I don't recall making any server side changes either.

Here's my `security.yaml` if that's of help

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        lazy: true
        provider: app_user_provider
        custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: logout
            target: login
        login_throttling:
            max_attempts: 3
```

Comment: do you use the same APP_ENV in local/remote?

Comment: yes, i am using the same one @johnSmith

Comment: hard to tell, maybe comparing `bin/console debug:config security` on the two system helps, or maybe theres a specific diference in the .env files that may cause, maybe u can find sth. in the log, and last but not least, i guess u cleared the caches :)

Comment: there are a few differences, but i'm not able to tell if they're big ones with my experience of 4 months, would you mind to [take a look](https://www.textcompare.org/?id=61e81fd23fea489855ff2d23)? @johnSmith

Comment: i took a look but have no clue :/

Comment: sad to hear, but thanks 